# How to populate one form data into another form on same page before submit is clicked using ajax or js?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am new to ajax and javascript.
I want to populate a entry form data into another form on the same page before it is submitted.

That means i want to display the name,gender etc of registration form in another form on the same page before it is submitted with click button event.

Please anybody post some examples.

Comment: Can you clarify?  It's unclear what you're trying to do.  Are you just trying to populate fields on the page from other fields on the page without posting to the server?  Can you provide some kind of mocked example?

Comment: Yes i want to populate entered data in the fields onto the another form on d same page before posting data here is the example http://www.vistaprint.co.uk/vp/ns/studio3.aspx?pf_id=064&combo_id=233462&free_studio_gallery=true&referer=http%3a%2f%2fwww.vistaprint.co.uk%2fvp%2fns%2fdefault.aspx%3flangid%3d2%26xnav%3dipaddr%26rd%3d23%26GP%3d6%252f6%252f2011%2b8%253a55%253a41%2bAM%26GPS%3d1566772367%26GNF%3d0%26GPLSID%3d&rd=2

Answer (score 0):

(In response to your comment on the question above...)

Ah, that example is significantly more complex than previously implied.  The target in that example isn't a form, it's an image.  Do you have functionality in your server-side code already for generating the image?

Posting the AJAX to the server is very much the easy part in this case.  Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for example, you can do something like [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'somepage.php',
  data: data,
  success: function() {
    alert('success!');
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

The variable 'data' would be built from your form elements.  Possibly something like this:

```
var data = '';
data = data + 'somevalue=' + $('#formElement').val();
data = data + 'anothervalue=' + $('#aDifferentElement').val();
// etc.
```

What the code essentially does is submit an HTTP POST to the supplied URL with the supplied data, and then run the supplied "success" function upon a successful result.  You can also add an "error" function for an error result.

In your case, the result looks like it's an image.  So you'd end up setting the `src` attribute on an `img` tag to the resulting image.  Something like this:

```
$('#imageElement').attr('src', someString);
```

I'm not sure exactly how they're doing it in that example, but you can certainly look through the code and step through it in Firebug to see what you can find.  The response appears to be the actual image, not a link to the image.  But you can design yours either way.